# Locating Core Data’s sqlite database on Mac OS X app

Tags: macos, core-data

Where I can find Core Data’s sqlite database of Mac OS X application?

I have found it, but it's *.momd folder with 3 files (VersionInfo.plist, *.mom *.omo). How can I see the contents of it?

Comment: I have found it, but it's *.momd folder with 3 files (VersionInfo.plist, *.mom *.omo). How can I see the contents of it?

Comment: MOMD files are not the database. The database is a set SQLite database files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On OS X 10.7 Lion when the app is sandboxed, it is stored in:

```
~/Library/Containers/com.yourcompany.yourAppName/
```

Answer (score 2):

The persistent store in Core Data is just a file. So it's most likely in your Documents directory if it's a user's document. If it's an internal store, then it may be in the bundle, or may be put somewhere like ~/Library/Application Support.

Answer (score 1):

In High Sierra, SQLite file is saved in **~/Library/Application Support/[YourAppName]**

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed it getting stored in
`/Users/<username>/Library/Containers/<appbundleid>/Data/Library/Application%20Support/<AppName>/<DataModel>.sqlite`

So in my case following was the path of the test app
`/Users/kaunteya.s/Library/Containers/com.kaunteya.T1/Data/Library/Application%20Support/T1/T2.sqlite`

Answer (score -3):

You can find the sqlite file under `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[SDK version]/Applications/[App GUID]/Documents`

To inspect the contents of the database file, you could use this firefox extension: [Sqlite-manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/)

Comment: Nope. The question pertains to iOS, the question was asking about OS X.