# GUI to show persistant store contents on iPhone device

Tags: ios, core-data, persistent-storage

My app takes data from CLLocation and saves it into a db via CoreData. Question is can I view the contents of the db via a GUI?

I've searched around in Xcode and Instruments but no luck so far.

(Prferably without resorting to command line sql!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use UITableView with fetchedResultsController, it would even give you sorting for free.

Another way, that is not free, but let's you see and edit your store is **Core Data Editor**.

http://christian-kienle.de/CoreDataEditor

If you want to get the store from your Device,you can find it (usually) in Documents folder. If it is Jailbreaken, you can use iExplorer to browse your iPhone file system.Find your app folder there, documents,and very likely that your sql is there.

Comment: Ah, nice! Thanks Nikita. There's too much data for a UITable. Just need to figure out how to get the store off the device and onto the laptop.....

Comment: hmmm, I can get the .sqlite file but CoreDataEditor needs the application to be compliles in a .app package...

Comment: Set your Scheme for Release and then in **Product** Build for Archive.Then,in your resouces you'll find your .app

Comment: The problem with releasing the app is that you can't then look at the CoreLocation data that the iPhone GPS has saved.

Just found http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/ which works perfectly. Just ashame it took £20 and 2 hrs work to find it :/

Comment: Thank you,will take a look at this too

Comment: Only if you use .sqlite as the persistent store.

I'm gonna vote up this thread though, coz I think it address some issues and answers the question :) Or I would if I could!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here for a sqlite db editor, it's a firefox plugin, free and easy to use: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10036813/81729